# AnyLogic - custom condition for last exit port in selectOutput5

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Is there a way to specify a condition for the last exit port (fifth) in the selectOutput5 block and to ensure that if that condition is not met (false), the block will return to evaluating the condition for exit port 1, then exit port 2, and so on? The idea is to create kind of a loop, so that if none of the five conditions are met, it will return to evaluating condition 1 and so on.

Comment: This will always create an infinite loop so you would never actually want to do this. @Emile`s answer below works around that by using a small delay. That will work but is not good model design ;)

Comment: I agree with you Benjamin in general, but the question requested a loop specifically :P
One better approach in such situations would be to use the Wait block and free the agent whenever one of the conditions is met.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/answers. While is does work with your configuration @Emile (with the "delay" block), it seems to work better with the "wait" block to free the agent when a condition is met. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the below configuration and add a very small delay time (e.g. 0.1 seconds)
[image]